# Как защитить коммерческий Java продукт?

Tags: java, архитектура, защита

Подскажите как можно защитить свой Java продукт от финансовых потерь? В основном беспокоят пиратство и плагиат исходного кода. Я так понял всякие обфускаторы не очень то и помогут. Лучше решение которое я вижу это вынести весь функционал на сервер в интернет, но дело  дело осложняется тем, что обязательное условие - возможность работать оффлайн, да и производительность приложения пострадает.  Может быть вынести часть функционала на сервер? Например основной функционал будет доступен, а всякие дополнительные фичи только через интернет.

Может кто знает ещё варианты, поделитесь пожалуйста архитектурными решениями etc.

Comment: Кроме выноса на сервер — скорее всего никак, и это касается не только java

Comment: 100% защиты в природе нет. Ломаются все продукты, от операционных систем до игр. Вопрос тут в другом - какие вы можете предпринять меры, чтобы взлом вашего продукта просто не стоил бы этих трудозатрат?

Comment: По поводу возможности работы оффлайн - это растяжимое понятие. По сути да, если нет требований поддерживать все фичи в оффлайне, то можно сделать свой сервер. Но окупятся ли вам затраты на свой сервер в сравнении с убытками от пиратства? Или вы в принципе позиционируете свой продукт как saas решение?

Comment: Да затраты на сервер - не проблема, подписочная модель покроет всё что мне нужно.

Comment: Затраты на сервер должны быть не решением какой то специфической проблемы, а частью вашего бизнес плана. Выделение сервера по сути меняет вашу систему прлностью. Вам, вероятно, и настольная прога больше не нужна будет, если, например, html5 оффлайн возможностей будет достаточно.

Comment: Вы, может, даже не сервер сделать захотите, а облачный бекенд, чтобы снизить свои затраты.